# Select Old Values and Replace some columns before insert using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I ran into an issue while trying to do a mysql INSERT INTO ... SELECT but I get some errors due to the way I formatted my query. I would appreciate your kind assistance.

Here is the Query:

```
INSERT INTO job_question_options (REPLACE(j_question_id, 2, 130), opt)
    SELECT s.j_question_id, s.option as opt
    FROM job_question_options s
    WHERE s.j_question_id = 2
```

**Note**: I want to be able to replace the j_question_id with a new value when inserting into the db.

**ERROR SUMMARY**

Static analysis:

10 errors were found during analysis.

A comma or a closing bracket was expected (near "(" at position 41)
Unexpected token. (near "j_question_id" at position 42)
Unexpected token. (near "," at position 55)
Unexpected token. (near "2" at position 57)
Unexpected token. (near "," at position 58)
Unexpected token. (near "130" at position 60)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 63)
Unexpected token. (near "," at position 64)
Unexpected token. (near "opt" at position 66)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 69)
SQL query: Documentation

```
INSERT INTO job_question_options (REPLACE(j_question_id, 2, 130), opt) 
SELECT s.j_question_id, s.option as opt 
FROM job_question_options s 
WHERE s.j_question_id = 2
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'REPLACE(j_question_id, 2, 130), opt) SELECT s.j_question_id, s.option as opt
>   ' at line 1

Please kindly help

Comment: What are you doing with the `replace`? That should be in the `select` I'd think. Is there PHP to this, seems to just be a `mysql` question.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I have already fixed it. Thanks. I used INSERT INTO ... SELECT .... without the replace function.